# GTK Sharp reset/redraw entry box

Tags: c#, gtk#

I'm trying to implement simple GUI for app but i just don't know how to reset entry box output(There's no methods for it in GTK Sharp)

So does somebody have idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [**Entry's** members section at the Mono's online docs for Gtk#](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3AGtk.Entry), you have the property *Text*.

```
var edName = new Entry( "John Doe" );
// ...
edName.Text = "Jane Doe";
// ...
string chosenName = edName.Text;
```

You just change that property when you need to reset the entry, and read it when you need to get the user's input.

Check out this nice [Gtk# tutorial from ZetCode](http://zetcode.com/gui/gtksharp/).